# How to view the full text in DropDownList in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, html-select

I have one GridView named as "`gvDUDesc`", Which has the following columns:

```
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ControlStyle-Width="100%"
       ItemStyle-Width="200px">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDUDescription" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDescriptionEvent" Font-Size="Smaller">
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

I want to show the full text of the DropDownList which is placed inside the GridView. I don't know how to achieve this?

I tried the below thing for the normal individual DropDownList. It works fine. But for the DropDownList inside the GridView, it is not working.

I have a separate style.css file in my solution , add the styles in that style.css file

```
.ctrDropDown
{
    width:154px;
    font-size:11px;
}
.ctrDropDownClick
{
    font-size: 11px;
    width:auto;
}
.plainDropDown
{
    width:154px;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

in aspx file,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDropID" runat="server" CssClass="ctrDropDown"
                  onBlur="this.className='ctrDropDown';"
                  onMouseDown="this.className='ctrDropDownClick';" 
                  onChange="this.className='ctrDropDown';">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And I remove the width property in the above syntax.

How to do this for the DropDownList which is placed inside the GridView?

Comment: make grid view itemstyle width more than actual size of dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put below markup in the page. It will take required width for your dropdownlist.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ControlStyle-Width="100%" ItemStyle-  Width="200px">
    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDUDescription" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDescriptionEvent" Font-Size="Smaller">
          </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle  Width="300px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: yes. i can view that, but without increasing the item style width, how to do that? Suppose if the text has more characters then we can't increase the itemstyle of one column in gridview. It may affects the design.